# Nginx reverse proxy configuration issue

Tags: tomcat, nginx

i have deployed a webapp on tomcat on digital ocean droplet

The structure of the war file is (Servelet is the webapp name)

```
Servelet
    ---- WEB-INF/classes/folder/FileXyz.class
```

Now on my local pc when i want to access this i do:

```
localhost:8080/Servelet/FileXyz
```

I deployed the same war on the tomcat on digital ocean but this time with a domain connected : server.foodini.co.in

Now i can access the same file using:

```
server.foodini.co.in:8080/Servelet/FileXyz
```

This works fine.

Now i wanted to have an nginx in front which would listen to the 80 port and forward all requests to the tomcat webapp via a reverse proxy

I edited the default file under /etc/nginx/sites-available
under the server configuration, i added:

```
  server_name server.foodini.co.in

  root /opt/tomcat/webapps/Servelet

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
```

Now when i do

```
server.foodini.co.in
```

It opens the tomcat default page as expected

But

```
server.foodini.co.in/Servelet/FileXyz

(adding the port 8080 again works)
```

gives a 404 and the same 404 for all other paths, can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Host Header when passing the request to the proxied server, otherwise nginx will override the Host header with the variable [$proxy_host](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#var_proxy_host), which in this case would be `127.0.0.1:8080` and you want it to be `server.foodini.co.in:8080`. So just add this to the `location /` block:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
```

Comment: Perfect, yep, that's what it was... Was stuck for like a whole day man, you saved my ass... Thanks

Comment: Any idea how i can stop just the default server.foodini.co.in from showing the tomcat page?

Comment: You mean the default tomcat page on root / ?

Comment: Yea the root index.jsp .... This tomcat is just the backend access layer... No gui component.... Is there a way to redirect the index to say another domain?

Comment: You can do an exact match on nginx `location = /` or `location = /index.jsp` etc, then do a redirect. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location, https://bjornjohansen.no/nginx-redirect

Comment: The exact match will prevail over `location /`

Comment: Oh cool, i was gonna add a redirect header in the jsp but this is better... Not really a server guy so this is all new to me :'D

Comment: No worries. Is much better to offload that sort of logic if you can to nginx

Comment: Exact match index.jsp didn't work and = / didn't Work for server.foodini.co.in without the trailing slash, i resorted to just renaming the index.jsp file in tomcat and letting it fall to 404

Comment: mmh I understand why `index.jsp` didn't work in your case because you don't actually hit /index.jsp. For getting it to work without the trailing slash you might need a location regex. Something like `location ~  ^(/)?$ { ...`

Comment: Amazing, i used your regex and if some wise ass ends up guessing what i renamed my index file too, even that has a redirect returned... You are amazing my friend

Comment: You don't have to leave it up to a wise ass guessing :), you can still have `location = /index.jsp` and put the redirect for that one too, as long as the request is  `server.foodini.co.in/index.jsp` it will work, just needs to be an exact match